# Google Sheets - combining split with regexextract/regexreplace

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I'm working on a workbook that has one column setup correctly. Essentially, it is setup such that this value:

> This is Foo, and I hate it
> This is Bar, and I like it
> And this is Baz

is displayed as separated by comma, like:

> This is Foo, and I hate it,This is Bar, and I like it,And this is Baz

I need to find a way to split these values. I first thought of using Split with comma as delimiter, but it won't work because some individual values have commas in them.

I'm thinking of using regex to capture a comma followed by a capital letter (like ,[A-Z]) and to combine this with the split function. Is this possible? Basically to split the cell using the comma and capital letter as delimiter.

Tried using Regexreplace to replace a comma followed by a capital letter with a delimiter that's not a comma:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A2, ",[A-Z]", ";")
```

Which then results to something like

`This is Foo, and I hate it;his is Bar, and I like it;nd this is Baz`

I can then split them using a semicolon, but then I lose the first character of the other values.

Comment: You can try capturing the capital letter and place it back into the string: [replace `,([A-Z])` with `;$1`](https://regex101.com/r/u0wzt4/1). There might be better ways to do this than a fragile regex replace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And if you use SUBSTITUTE the other way round?, You change comma and space with semicolon, then split by commas:

```
=SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,", ","; "),",")
```

[image]

And if you want back the commas, use ARRAYFORMULA and SUBSTITUTE wrapping that formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,", ","; "),","),";",","))
```

[image]

Comment: PS: yes, you can use REGEXREPLACE instead of SUBSTITUTE